# Switch on verbosity diagnostic on sql execute powershell

Tags: powershell

I have script, which connect to db. I need get technical info about execute script. Or when in my sql srcipt exist mistake,I see very scant information. But I need detail of error. How can I get more detail info?

```
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $connection.Open()
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Animal"
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
    $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
    $table.Load($result)
    $table
            //how get info
    $connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

After your code executes run  `Error[0] | fl -Force` to get the details of (last) error.